# How to install rpm in a system without yum, apt-get, make and a c compiler...?

Tags: linux, google-kubernetes-engine, chromium-os

I have a cluster deployed from google container engine where all my docker containers are deployed, i would like to install rpm in one of the machines in the cluster. But none of the machines has yum or apt-get or make or a c compiler.

The image used is : gci-beta-55-8872-47-0

Description of the image: Google, Container-Optimized OS, beta 55-8872.47.0, Kernel: ChromiumOS-4.4.4 Kubernetes: 1.4.5 Docker: 1.11.2

Comment: consider researching cross-compilers. Build your executables on a x-compiler equipped machine, then copy it to your cluster as needed. Otherwise, this Q is way too broad for StackOverflow, as it will be a death by a 100 sub-questions. Sorry, but good luck.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: You could use `rpm2cpio`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Container-Optimized OS image is not designed to have a package manager (see https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/node-image-migration#managing_software_on_container-vm_image).

If you need to install rpm on the host OS (rather than running everything in containers), you should consider [running the Debian-based container image instead](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/node-image-migration#opt-out):

```
gcloud container clusters create --image-type=container_vm [CLUSTER_NAME]
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand that. But, installing rpm in such a system sounds like an interesting challenge.

Comment: The system comes with a command called `toolbox` that runs a container that is specifically designed to allow you to do things like install custom packages.